# Meteor and #each scoping

Tags: javascript, meteor

I m actually developping a simplistic application using meteorjs and I m facing a problem.

Actually, I m having a template with an #each statement like following :

```
<template name="insidePlanning">
  <div class="row m-t">
    <div class="backGrey col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        {{#each users}}
          <div class="col-md-{{countUsersCol}}">
            {{name}}
          </div>
        {{/each}}
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class=" col-md-4">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" class="form-control" />
        </div>
      </form>

      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        {{#each taskNotAffected}}
          <li>{{title}}</li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Everything is working fine excepted the {{countUsersCol}} ...

Here's my template helper :

```
  Template.insidePlanning.helpers({
    countUsersCol:function(){
      if(this.users){
        return Math.round(12/this.users.length);
      }
      return 0;
    }
  });
```

In fact, when I put {{countUsersCol}} inside of the #each statement, I always get 0. If I put it just above the #each, it displays 6 (the value that I actually need.). So, in conclusion, #each creates a different scope inside of its statement...

I tried using {{../countUsersCol}} but nothing happens and I dont know what to do actually.

Could you help me a little please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `users` are part of the `#each` block's **parent** data-context: inside the loop, `this` will only contain what is in the current single `user` document you are working on. You will need to use [`Template.parentData()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_parentdata) in order to get data of an upper level from within a helper.

```
  Template.insidePlanning.helpers({
    countUsersCol:function(){
      var parentData = Template.parentData(1);
      if(parentData.users){
        return Math.round(12/parentData.users.length);
      }
      return 0;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `each` is used with a cursor, so I am going to assume you used that. You are using `this.users.length`, and if `this.users` is a cursor, you should not get a `.length`. You should try `this.users.count()`.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. The fact is that I have the wanted result outside the #each box. When I console.log(this) inside of my function, I have my child element, and I cant access the parent function.

Comment: Maybe you can use `Template.instance().data`?

Answer (score 0):

So, when you are inside of an each block, the `this` keyword will reference one of the objects that you are iterating over in the `{{#each}}` block. So, lets assume that your each block's "users" is a helper that returns a list of users you have subbed to `return Meteor.users.find({});`. Using this, within the `{{#each}}` block returns one user doc like: `{name: "eric", occupation: "doctor"}` or whatever you sub to. So, in order to get the count of every user you sub to for the `{{#each}}` block, you will need a helper that counts all the records. something simplistic might be: `Template.myTemplate.helpers({ userCount: function() { return Meteor.users.find({}).count();} });`